# intermittent "No result backend" exception

Tags: celery

Given the two very simple files:

Tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Webapp.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.execute import send_task

#random_name = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://')
r1 = send_task('tasks.add',(1,1))
print(r1.get())
```

If I run the code as is, I'm getting the error
"NotImplementedError: No result backend is configured.".

If I just remove the # (before random_name = ...), everything is working fine (the program prints 2).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I got an official answer here:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6744

Basically follow https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html
, you need a celeryconfig.py file at your PYTHONPATH for celery to have app configured correctly.